# How to Fix - Changing the arrival time does not change the length of time to the destination

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a quick list of potential house addresses and show the distance and time taken to get to my destinations e.g. work or sport.

I grabbed a script for this and it works fine but my hunch is that it does not include traffic data.

I included the arrival time for my destination and regardless of whether I put midnight or peak hour in the time to my destination will remain the same.

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type,arrive_time) { 
var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  mapObj.setArrive(arrive_time);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }

}
```

As an example:
Expected result would be a trip at midnight to take 10 mins and at peak hour to take 20
Actual result shows both trips taking 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get `duration_in_traffic` for each leg in addition to `duration`.

Based on the Google Maps directions docs, it looks like you need to specify that the travel mode is `driving`, and you need to include a `departure_time` - presumably using `.setMode()` and `.setDepart()`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsAdvanced

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue as original poster, changing the depart time does change the  `duration_in_traffic` but changing arrival time doesn't do anything it seems

```
/**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed
  
  // Setting arrival time
  var depart = new Date(2023, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0);
  var arrival = new Date(2023, 5, 8, 8, 20, 0);

  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setMode("driving")
    .setDepart(depart)
    .setArrive(arrival)
    .setOrigin(start_address)
    .setDestination(end_address)
    .getDirections();
  
  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];
  
  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];



  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration_in_traffic"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration_in_traffic"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }
  
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34345327)